# Debug MacOS optimized battery charging

Tags: battery, monterey, apple-silicon

I have an issue with the optimized battery charging in MacOS. Namely:

Around two months ago, while travelling, I anticipated I would need 100% of my battery and requested my Macbook charge to 100% [via the "Charge to Full Now" option in the battery menu bar](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212049#resume). Ever since, across multiple chargers, I have not seen it fall back to 80% anymore, and it spends the **vast** majority of its time plugged in.

Is there a way to debug this feature, so I can get an idea what's wrong? Or perhaps reset its state completely?

Comment: How did you „request a charge to 100%“?

Comment: @nohillside "Charge to Full Now" as per the first image [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212049)

Comment: Please make the question stand on its own and include relevant details directly.

Comment: Something similar happened to me earlier this year; it took about 2-3 months for the Mac to return to an optimized battery charging regime.